# MS Access Sub Query Does Not Stop Running

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to write a query in Access to pull records from a table where Field_Three contains a certain string of text. Please take a look at what I have below which I adapted from [here](http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html).

```
SELECT [Table_One].[Field_One], [Table_One].[Field_Two]
FROM [Table_One]
WHERE
    (SELECT [Table_One].[Field_Three]
    FROM [Table_One]
    WHERE [Table_One].[Field_Three]="Text");
```

When I attempt to run this I do not get an error it just doesn't stop running. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For future reference: [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271).

Comment: It is unclear what you are attempting as subquery does not correlate at all with outer query. You may have in anonymizing actual query dropped or changed fields/tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a subquery for this.

Just use an ordinary `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT [Table_One].[Field_One], [Table_One].[Field_Two]
FROM [Table_One]
WHERE
[Table_One].[Field_Three] = "Text";
```

Comment: Well, the question isn't that clear, but I assumed he wanted that because field three should _contain_ a certain string, but I'll revert it since the question is pretty unclear about that

Comment: Thanks @Erik von Asmuth! However, I think I phrased the question improperly. I am trying to sum one of these fields but only when Field_Three contains a certain string. I am not doing a good job at explaining it but i think I have found another way. I will mark your answer as correct because by the way I phrased it you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

As said before you don't have to subquery to do this. This query doesn't make any sense to do and you are making SQL do a lot more for nothing.

Just use:

```
WHERE [Table_One].[Field_Three] = "Text"
```

However the reason your code is endlessly running is that you don't have a condition to apply your subquery.

If you are going to use that query it should look like this:

```
SELECT [Table_One].[Field_One], [Table_One].[Field_Two]
FROM [Table_One]
WHERE [Table_One].[Field_Three] IN
(
    SELECT [Table_One].[Field_Three] FROM [Table_One]
    WHERE [Table_One].[Field_Three]="Text"
);
```